# WebView2 - MHTML / MHT File Format

Tags: c#, html, webview2

Does Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 browser supports Web page archive file formats like mhtml/mtm?

Performed Loading of mht file to webview2 browser using navigate method. It's loading the HTML content but images or not getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it with a '`.mhtml`' file, saved by Edge. It works fine.

However, there is an old bug in Edge/Chrome that sets the file name to '**.html**' when it should be '**.mhtml**'.

If you try loading that file, you only load the html!

The solution is simple, rename the file to '**.mhtml**'.

Now it should load everything.